# Induced hermitic metric on the exterior algebra bundles

Tags: complex-geometry

Let X be a complex manifold equipped with an hermitic metric $h:T_X \times T_X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. For me it is clear that this induces an hermitian metric on the exterior algebra bundles $\bigwedge\nolimits^k T^*_X$.

My question is now, how does this induce an hermitian metric on the exterior algebra bundles $\bigwedge\nolimits^k T^*_{X,\mathbb{C}}$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^{p,q}T^*_{X,\mathbb{C}}$.

I would appreciate any help on this.